# Chroot on startup

Tags: linux, chroot, init.d, startup-scripts, busybox

I have a script that runs on startup, but it wont launch a application in chroot.

```
#!/bin/sh 
/usr/sbin/chroot /root/chrootdir/ /bin/sh -c "lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd.conf -m /lib" 
echo "script activated" >> /log/www.log
```

the log file is written/appended on startup, but the lighttpd server is not starting. 
Running the script when the box is running works fine and launches lighttpd. 
This is a embedded system running a linux kernel and busybox.
inittab triggers /etc/init.d/rcS that in turn run my start_www script. the start_www script is the last thing rcS launches.

**Update:**

> /bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libm.so.6: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory

but libm.so.6 is located in /root/chrootdir/lib/libm.so.6
what to do now? how do i specify the libm.so path?
tried the command "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib; lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd.conf -m /lib" without success.

**Update 2:**
. when i run the command:

> chroot /root/chrootdir/ /sbin/lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd.conf -m /lib

it launches the webserver without any warning or error. But when I launch the same script during startup, the script suddenly is unable to find the libs. Inside my chrootdir i got a .profile file containing:

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib

my guess is that the .profile settings file is not used during startup
how do i set the library path?

Comment: Append `> /log/lighttpd.log 2>&1` to the end of second line, then try again to see what happens.

Comment: i have /log/lighttpd/error.log and access.log, no errors where generated during startup. it is like it never runs at all.

Comment: No. I mean append it to the end of `/usr/sbin/chroot /root/chrootdir/ /bin/sh -c "lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd.conf -m /lib"` in your script to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file to see what's going on.

Comment: /bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libm.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

and: /root/chrootdir/lib/libm.so.6
thats strange..

Comment: `ldd /root/chrootdir/bin/sh`?

Comment: ldd does not exist. the root system is built with uClibc and the chrootdir is built with glibc.

Comment: Can you execute this commands? : `ldd /tools/bin/bash` and `ldd /bin/bash`

Comment: i do not have ldd

Comment: @Maidenone, `LD_DEBUG=files` is ur friend. See `man ld.so`

Comment: setting `LD_DEBUG=files` does not give any more debug info. the only output i get is : `/sbin/lighttpd: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. This file is only located in /lib in the chroot dir. the lighttpd MUST use the /root/chrootdir/lib, or it wont work because of different versions of libc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you rebuild glibc with that?

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-add-ons --libexecdir=/lib
```

Comment: this would have worked, but I ended up with the lazy solution. I creatied (in my chroot dir) a symlink from my /lib to /lib in the prefix path I used when I cross compiled glibc.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `chroot`-issuing `/bin/sh -c "lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd.conf -m /lib"` try running the same command inside shell-script put into chroot, kinda:

`/sbin/chroot /root/chrootdir/ /start_it_up.sh`

**UPD.**: *Well, accumulating everything I've suggested in my comments to that answer:*

1. `mount --bind` your parent system libs into chroot's lib dirs — at least to test whether it would work at all
2. Use ld's flag `LD_DEBUG=files` to find out what dependencies could some libraries have, since they also influence in overall failure to preload the target

Comment: Good idea, but the default terminal is still /bin/sh, which gives the same error. 
/bin/sh: error while loading shared libraries: libm.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @Maidenone, default what? Default shell? Well, have you tried running just `chroot /root/chrootdir/` — what's the output? + U can use `"#!/any/exec` in header, you know?

Comment: @Maidenone, also, according to `man chroot` you should be able to give all the args w/o shell: `chroot /root/chrootdir/ /path2/lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd.conf -m /lib` — just like that

Comment: `chroot /root/chrootdir/ /sbin/lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd.conf -m /lib` gives the following error: 
`/sbin/lighttpd: error while loading shared libraries: libpcre.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` and the libpcre.so.1 file is located in /root/chrootdir/lib/ the same error but another program. So i still need to define the path in some way.

Comment: @Maidenone, u still need to have every needed libs inside chroot, that's it.

Comment: @Maidenone, easiest way to accomplish it it `mount --bind` ur outside lib dir into chroot — at least for testing. If you need tight setup, u can copy needed libs by hands, but that's kinda tedious.

Comment: @Maidenone, and you can use `LD_DEBUG=files` to track what files are missing for those libs, ur program try to load, for e. g.: `LD_DEBUG=files chroot /wher2chroot /bin/false`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, will test this soon. 
Every lib i need exists in the chroot (and outside). when i run the command:
`chroot /root/chrootdir/ /sbin/lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd.conf -m /lib` it launches the webserver without any warning or error. It is when I launch the same script during startup that the script suddenly is unable to find the libs. I got a `.profile` file containing "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib" inside the chroot. my guess is that the .profile settings file is not used during startup.

Comment: @Maidenone, according to the `man ld.so` `/lib` should be searched by default: «In the default path /lib, and then /usr/lib.  If the binary was linked with the -z nodeflib linker option, this step is skipped.»
If u think the problem is with search path, then inspect `/etc/ld.so.conf` in chroot env, or populate it accordingly (`man ldconfig`) and make sure cache file is being created as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may create init script for lighttpd and then pass during exection LD_LIBRARY_PATH at command line, so you won't care about .profile and so on.
Syntax, for example

```
# LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/:/usr/local/lib/ myCommand
```

You may also use 'ldd' command to check linked libraries.